# В чем разница между управляющими символами \b и \f

Tags: java

В процессе изучения языка программирования java столкнулся с вопросом, ответ на который не могу никак найти.
УС `\b` - обычный пробел, как я понял, а `\f` - прогон страницы, но при использовании его с примитивными строками разницы с `\b` не увидел.

**Обновление**

Код `System.out.print("String\bstring");` и `System.out.print("String\fstring");`. Ведет себя одинаково. Вот я и заинтересовался, в чём же всё-таки разница, так как момент не ясен для меня.

Comment: распечатайте на матричном принтере или в консоли. Разница будет заметна. Правда, некоторые консоли могут его специфично обрабатывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Управляющие последовательности на то и управляющие, что они *управляют* выводом. Некоторые операции вывода могут поддерживать некоторые управляющие последовательности, но конечно не все.

Например, вряд ли `MessageBox` будет поддерживать прогон страницы, правильно?

Отсюда вопрос: в каком контексте вы используете управляющие символы? Покажите код, который ведёт себя непонятно.

Comment: Код System.out.print("String\bstring");
и System.out.print("String\fstring");
ведет себя одинаково. Вот я и заинтересовался в чём же всё таки разница, так как момент не ясен для меня.